# how to post and get php vars with jquery?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, post, get

i have a few php vars:

```
$test = 12345;
$test1 = "test1";
$test2 = "test2";
```

and i have a jquery function:

```
onlike:function(response){
    $('input#helpdiv').trigger('click');    
}
```

what i want is to pass those php vars through a jquery post to another `test.php` file.

I was thinking on something like this:

```
var test = <?php echo $test; ?>; 
var test1 = <?php echo $test1; ?>; 
var test2 = <?php echo $test2; ?>; 

onlike:function(response){
    $('input#helpdiv').trigger('click');
    $.post("test.php", { test, test1, test2 } );
}
```

and then how do i get them in the `test.php`? just like `$_GET["test"], ...`

any ideas on how to put this together?

thanks

Comment: What happens when you run the code as you have it now?

Comment: i haven't test it, i just write it really quick more as a pseudo code, because im not sure of the syntax

Comment: If you quote the string vars and provide variable names for the javascript object youre passing to the post function it will work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<script language='javascript'> 
 var test = "<?php echo $test; ?>"; 
  var test1 = "<?php echo $test1; ?>"; 
  var test2 = "<?php echo $test2; ?>"; 

  onlike:function(response){
      $('input#helpdiv').trigger('click');
      $.post("test.php", { test:test, test1:test1, test2:test2  } );
        }
 </script>
```

in test.php you can access them as $_POST['test'],$_POST['test1'],$_POST['test2']

EDIT:

to avoid problems caused by quotes in between the variable values, 
as explained in: [how to post and get php vars with jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7193962/how-to-post-and-get-php-vars-with-jquery)

```
  var test = "<?php echo json_encode($test); ?>";
```

and the values may be accesed in test.php as

```
 $test1 = json_decode($_POST['test'])
```

Comment: Yes that's a better response.

Comment: You have to be careful here to escape the values properly. If there's a quotation mark in any of the $test variables it'll break shit.

Comment: @Bill Criswell: you are right.. adding addslashes here and filtering with stripslashes in test.php .. can this solve the issue?

Comment: I did some research and it seems like it could get to be messy. I came across this post though and it seems thorough... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/168214/pass-a-php-string-to-a-javascript-variable-including-escaping-newlines

Answer (score 2):

```
var test = '<?php echo $test; ?>';
```

You need to put quotes around a value in JS

Also do you have those variables available when page loads ? As javascript will be rendered on page load it will take existing values at that time.

Also check http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/ for making call more clearner to handle response.

Answer (score 1):

Just to conclude the comments I made above: 1st quote the string literal vars e.g.

```
    $test = "test";
var test = '<?php echo $test; ?>';
```

Then add them as key value pairs to the object you're passing to the  post function e.g.

```
{ test: test }
```